# Spring Data Rest Links Disappear

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have been coming across a weird issue on my Spring Application + Spring Data Rest.

I have enabled @RestRepository to some of the DAOs there and can use the generated endpoints to make updates to the database.

The following is a sample response from curl:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/
{
  "_links" : {
    "resourceA" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/resourceA"
    },
    "resourceB" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/resourceB"
    },
    "resourceC" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/resourceC"
    },
    "resourceD" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/resourceD"
    },
    "resourceE" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/resourceE"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/profile"
    }
}
```

But after a few hours, sometimes days, these endpoints stop working. I can no longer use them and gets a 404 response in an attempt to do POSTs on the above endpoints.

The curl now is as follows:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9090/my-service/profile"
    }
}
```

For some reason, my spring data rest endpoints are down!! My application is still servicing requests as evident from the above response, but my Spring-Data-Rest endpoint are down.

The following are my spring configs:

```
server:
  port: 9090
  servlet.context-path: /my-service

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/my_service_db
    username: username
    password: password
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

Can someone please shed some light as to what is happening? I don't see any strange logs either. What can I do to further diagnose this issue?

My dependency versions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank You

Comment: Better put an runnable example project in Github. Hard to guess the cause from a few code snippet. My first guess is "is your repository interface public?"

Comment: Just an suggestion. Use git for source version control. Commit when you have a workable version. When you make a mistake, you can see the difference between current and last commit.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036378/spring-data-rest-repositories-occasionally-not-exported). Try upgrade the version of Spring Data REST

Comment: @yejianfengblue Thank you for responding. This was actually the initial release so we started off with this issue. Also, this issue kinda apprears after a day or two and I haven't found a reliable way to reproduce this. I know the above is not much to work with and I am sorry for that. At the end, I ended up bumping to latest spring-data versions in hope of fixing the issue, but will need to wait for a while to see if it manifests again.